# Is the result of the conditional operator an lvalue or rvalue?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

We know that the conditional operator returns an lvalue if its `Expr2` and `Expr3` are lvalues of the same type otherwise it returns an rvalue:

```
int main(){
   int a = 0, b = 0;
   (a == 1 ? a : b) = 1; // C++ OK. C: error. lvalue needed

   return 0;
}
```

- The code above compiles fines on C++ while it fails to compile on C.

Here is the output on C:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:20: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
(a == 1 ? a : b) = 1;
                ^
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that in C, the conditional operator always yields an rvalue, never an lvalue.  It doesn't seem to be explicitly stated in the Standard, but operators that do yield an lvalue are specifically mentioned as doing so, and `?:` isn't.

Comment: "We know that" followed by a false statement

Comment: If both operands are lvalues, you can make an lvalue result by doing `*(a==1 ? &a : &b)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, the result<sup>1</sup> of the conditional operator is an rvalue (a “value” in the terminology of the C standard) because C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `unary &` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue);…

Thus, while the result of the conditional operator is its second or third operand, that operand has been converted to a value and is no longer an lvalue.

As [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) notes, you can get the same effect as selecting an lvalue by selecting addresses of operands instead and then applying `*`:

```
*(a == 1 ? &a : &b) = 1;
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The result of the conditional operator is not a return value, as there is no function call involved, so there is no call-and-return, just an expression evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

In [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), there is a footnote that makes it clear that the result of a conditional operator is not an lvalue:

> #### 6.5.15 Conditional operator
>
> …
>
> ##### Semantics
>
> 4    The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the evaluation of
> the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated). The second
> operand is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the
> third operand is evaluated only if the first compares equal to 0; the
> result is the value of the second or third operand (whichever is
> evaluated), converted to the type described below.<sup>110)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>110)</sup> A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.

Furthermore, [in this later draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2346.pdf) (dated March, 2019), the wording hasn't changed significantly (except that the footnote is therein numbered 116, rather than 110).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where C++ and C differ.  In C the conditional operator results in an rvalue and therefore it cannot be the left side of an assignment.

Answer (score -2):

expression1? expression2 : expression3
If expression 1 has a true (non-zero) value, then the entire conditional expression takes the same value as expression 2 . If expression 1 has a false (null) value, then the entire conditional expression gets the same value as expression 3.

```
P r i m e r s
(5 > 3) ? 1 : 2 gets the value 1.
(3 > 5) ? 1 ; 2 gets the value 2.
(a > b) ? a : b gets a larger value among a or b. 
   The conditional operation itself is not a function that 
  returns a value.
```

Comment: The question is not about what **value** is produced by the conditional operator. The question is about the **type** of the value, specifically whether it is an *lvalue* that may be used on the left side of an assignment operator.

Comment: It seems to me that from what I have written, the answer to this question becomes obvious. If this is not the case, then I was mistaken.